# How to update rows from a table?

Tags: php, mysql-workbench

I am trying to update and delete rows from my table. My code works but Ive noticed that only the most recent row can be updated and deleted. What's wrong with the these codes? :-\

### This is my code:

```
 <?php
 /*code for displaying database tbl_category to html table*/
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","admin","learning_assessment");
$sql="Select * from tbl_category";
$rs=mysqli_query($con,$sql);
$rows=mysqli_fetch_array($rs); 

?>
<fieldset class="fieldset590">
<fieldset class="fieldset1" style="background-color:gray">
<fieldset><legend class="legend">Question Category</legend>
<form action="category_.php" method="post">
<input class="inputbox" type="text" name="category" id="category" />
<input type="submit" value="Save" class="submitbtns" /></fieldset></form>
<table border="1">
<tr>
<th width="500px"><font color="#6b0c36">QUESTION CATEGORIES</font></th>
<th width="300px"></th>
<th width="300px"></th>
</tr>
<?php do { ?>
<tr><form action="AdminCategory.php" method="post">
<td><input class="inputboxlargest" type="text" name="category" value="<?php echo $rows['category']; ?>" /></td>
<input type="hidden" name="idtbl_category" value="<?php echo $rows['idtbl_category'];?>"  />
<td><input class="submitbtns" type="submit" name="update" value="UPDATE" /></td>
<td><input class="submitbtns" type="submit" name="delete" value="DELETE" /></td>
</tr>
<?php } while($rows=mysqli_fetch_array($rs));?>
</table><br /><br /><Br /><br /><br />

<br /><br />
</fieldset>
</fieldset>

</th>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
<?php
mysqli_free_result($rs);
?>

<?php
if(isset($_POST['delete'])){
$deletequery="delete from tbl_category where idtbl_category='$_POST[idtbl_category]'";
$deleters=mysqli_query($con,$deletequery);

}

if(isset($_POST['update'])){
$updatequery="update tbl_category set category='$_POST[category]' where idtbl_category='$_POST[idtbl_category]'";
$updaters=mysqli_query($con,$updatequery);
}
?>
```

---

THANK YOU!!!!

Comment: You are missing </form> element.

Comment: Moreover, your form element is inside do loop. is that what you want? having each from for each set of record?

Comment: There's a conflict with the $rows array... use `while(){}` instead of `do{}while()`

Comment: And move the Update/Delete code before all other code, because if a user will delete a row for example, he will take all rows from db, then the row will be deleted, but he will also see the deleted one. If you will move the delete/update code at the top, the rows will be updated/deleted before they will be shown

Comment: I think </form> element doesn't matter.. Uhm, I don't get it? My table goes like, 3 columns: CATEGORY, EDIT, DELETE and the edit and delete are buttons. WITH THAT CODES Only the last row(recent) can be updated and delete, when I click delete [for example out of 5 rows] in row 2, after refreshing-- it wasn't the second row, the 5th row was deleted. ;-( Same with update, when I update row 2, after refreshing nothing has been change. @kayra THANKS.

Comment: Thank you! @artur99 that would work, I THINK! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because your submitting one form. Only one form can submitted at a time. You should put all the `category` inputs in one form and create an array of `category` values. After that you can use javascript to customise the `action` tag on the form before submitting. It's not the 'beautifull' way but it works.

Your HTML / javascript code:

```
 <?php
 /*code for displaying database tbl_category to html table*/
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","admin","learning_assessment");
$sql="Select * from tbl_category";
$rs=mysqli_query($con,$sql);
$rows=mysqli_fetch_array($rs); 

?>
<fieldset class="fieldset590">
<fieldset class="fieldset1" style="background-color:gray">
<fieldset><legend class="legend">Question Category</legend>
<form action="category_.php" method="post">
<input class="inputbox" type="text" name="category" id="category" />
<input type="submit" value="Save" class="submitbtns" /></fieldset></form>
<table border="1">
<tr>
<th width="500px"><font color="#6b0c36">QUESTION CATEGORIES</font></th>
<th width="300px"></th>
<th width="300px"></th>
</tr>
<form action="AdminCategory.php" id="formAdminCategory" method="post">
<?php do { ?>
<tr>
<td><input class="inputboxlargest" type="text" name="category[<?php echo $rows['idtbl_category'];?>]" value="<?php echo $rows['category']; ?>" /></td>
<td><input class="submitbtns" type="submit" name="update" idtbl="<?php echo $rows['idtbl_category'];?>" value="UPDATE" /></td>
<td><input class="submitbtns" type="submit" name="delete" idtbl="<?php echo $rows['idtbl_category'];?>" value="DELETE" /></td>
</tr>
<?php } while($rows=mysqli_fetch_array($rs));?>
</table></form><br /><br /><Br /><br /><br />

<br /><br />
</fieldset>
</fieldset>

</th>
</tr>
</table>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).on('click', 'input[name="update"], input[name="delete"]', function(e)
    {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#formAdminCategory').attr('action', 'AdminCategory.php?action='+$(this).attr('name')+'&id='+$(this).attr('idtbl'));
        $('#formAdminCategory').submit();

    })
</script>

</body>
</html>
<?php
mysqli_free_result($rs);
?>
```

You can catch that by read the `$_GET` parameter `action` for the submitted action. If it is `update` you can loop through the `category` array:

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['action']) && $_GET['action'] == 'delete'){
$deletequery="delete from tbl_category where idtbl_category=".$_GET['id'];
$deleters=mysqli_query($con,$deletequery);

}

if(isset($_GET['action']) && $_GET['action'] == 'update'){

$categories = $_POST['category'];
foreach($categories as $id=>$category)
{
    $updatequery="update tbl_category set category='".$category."' where idtbl_category=".$id;
    $updaters=mysqli_query($con,$updatequery);

}

}
```

Also note that you should do the `update` and `delete` actions BEFORE you show the form. Else you need to refresh the page after you submitted a form to show the changed data.

Comment: I am so beginner :-( Thank you @S.Pols ! God bless you. I will do your script. Hopefully, Id understand those scripts. :-) THANK YOU VERY MUCH!